# Velocity profile in a triangular duct (Derivation)

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, fluid-dynamics

How do I find a velocity profile of an incompressible fluid in a triangular duct. Can someone point me to a step-by-step solution so that I could understand the process of derivation of the final form of the velocity profile.

Edit #1: So, based on the parameters that I have. I have reduced the N-S equation to the following form: $$\frac{\partial p}{\partial x} = \mu (\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial y^{2}} + \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial z^{2}})$$

I assume boundary conditions are as follows: $$u_{x}(z=h)=0$$ and the triangle is defined by three half-planes: $$\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\bigg)a \geq z$$ $$ z \geq \sqrt{3}y$$ $$z \geq -\sqrt{3}y$$.

And I'm stuck from here.

Comment: The solution is given in the second edition of Bird, et al. Transport Phenomena,
Wiley. Problem 3.B.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For unidirectional, laminar flow the $x-$component of velocity $u$ depends only on coordinates $y$ and $z$. The components of velocity in the other directions are identically zero.  The $y-$ and $z-$momentum equations reduce to

$$\frac{\partial p}{ \partial y} = \frac{\partial p}{ \partial z}  = 0.$$

As you stated, the Navier-Stokes equations reduce to

$$\nabla^2u = \frac{\partial^2 u}{ \partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{ \partial z^2} = \frac{1}{\mu} \frac{\partial p}{\partial x}.$$

Since, $u$ depends only on $y$ and $z$ and $p$ does not, it follows that the partial derivative of the pressure with respect to $x$ must be a constant

$$\frac{1}{\mu} \frac{\partial p}{\partial x} = G,$$

and we have a form of Poisson's equation

$$\nabla^2 u = G.$$

This PDE is satisfied at all points in a region $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ corresponding to a cross-section of the interior of the duct. Additionally, we have the no-slip boundary condition applied at the interior walls

$$u|_{\partial \Omega} = 0.$$

*There is no closed-form solution to this problem on the specified triangular region in terms of elementary functions.*

Approximate numerical solutions can be obtained readily.  The most common approaches for problems of this type are finite element or boundary integral methods.